# Are depictions of the prophet PBUH forbidden Islamically?

Tags: prophets, drawing

I always thought this question was asked but can not seem to find it on the website. I would like the input/knowledge of people on their interruption of the ruling of Islam when it comes to drawing the prophet PBUH. Please provide sources from the Quran and Sunnah forbidding such actions.

Comment: Unless there's a valid reason to expect the answer here to be any different from the ruling of drawing people in general, this looks to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Many people believe that drawing is haram, and mabye think otherwise. I won't say it is haram, as not everyone worships what they draw, but I will say that I myself have stopped drawing long ago. On the day of judgement, those who drew will be tortured until they bring life to what they drew, but they will never be able to. Also in another Hadith the Prophet came home one day and saw a curtain with a picture on it and he got extremely angry and ordered it to be destroyed. We also know that angels do not enter a house in which there is a dog or image. Now from these we can come to the conclusion that drawing the Prophet (pbuh) is just as wrong, if not worse. This is due to the following reasons:

- His honourable title and status to us
- In the future people may take this as a norm to draw him and eventually start worshiping him too

Some ahadiths include:
-Hazrat Umar RA narrates that the Prophet PBUH has said: verily those who make pictures will be punished on the day of resurrection, it will be said to them :give life to what you have created

Abu Hurairah RA said that i heard the Prophet PBUH saying: Allah SWT said : "Who is more unjust than he who tries to create what i created, they should try creating an atom or a grain or a barely"